# How do I enable Sulu API to guest accounts?

Tags: symfony, sulu

I am looking to find a way how to enable Sulu (Admin?) API accessible outside admin area.
To be more specified, to be accessible without account (session).

For example route "/admin/api/snippets"
This url works when you are logged in as admin, but I need it to work even if guest is visiting it, without account.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the symfony firewall the way you want it currently all behind is `/admin` is behind a login but you can change the [access control](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html) the way you like it. Be aware that the API is build for admin users and you maybe better to create your own API endpoint to not leak any unwanted informations.